# clojure 1.8 string replace with a string that has '\\r'

Tags: clojure

I tried this in REPL:

[image]

and when I put these 2 lines in a clj file, `\\ruby` gives `ruby`, but `\ruby` gives a `return` and `uby`.

I know `\r` is special.

How can I get `\ruby` in a clj file? why in REPL `\ruby` = `\ruby`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`(clojure.string/replace s match replacement)`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/replace) documentation says that the replacement is literal and no characters are treated specially in strings but the `$1` `$2` and so.

If you want to you use your replacement as it is then you can use the [`(clojure.string/re-quote-replacement r)`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/re-quote-replacement) to quote it. But if you check that function it produces 4 backspaces for a backspace:

```
(clojure.string/re-quote-replacement \\) ;;=> "\\\\"
```

So it seems that backslash should be escaped, therefore `\\\\` should work:

```
(clojure.string/replace "abc<def>" #"(\w+)<(\w+)>" "\\\\ruby{$1}{$2}") ;;=> "\\ruby{abc}{def}"
```

Comment: It works. Now I get a single \ in the output. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot - couldn't wait to test your answer.